# Pass array to function from specific index in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I am new to C# (previously working on C++), I used to pass array to function with specific index. Here is the code in C++,

```
void MyFunc(int* arr) { /*Do something*/ }

//In other function
int myArray[10];
MyFunc(&myArray[2]);
```

**Can I do something like this in C# .Net*** *?**

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do such a thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Array is Enumerable, you can make use of [LINQ function `Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx).

```
void MyFunc( int[] array ){ /*Do something*/ }

int[] myArray = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
MyFunc( myArray.Skip(2) );
```

Comment: It worked I jst have to add ToArray after skip statement. myArray.Skip(1).ToArray()

Comment: @vrajs5: think about making MyFunc accepting IEnumerable<int>, if MyFunc processes the array one after one element anyway. ToArray() creates a copy of myArray.

Comment: Ah, that's cool, I've never seen the Linq Skip function before. Personally though, that seems so inefficient i think i would just change MyFunc to internally skip first 2 elements, or even add a new param for element number for MyFunc to start at... I guess it depends...

Answer (score 0):

The linq version is my preferred one. However it will prove to be very very inefficient.

You could do

```
int myArray[10];
int mySlice[8];
Array.Copy(myArray, 2, mySlice, 0);
```

and pass mySlice to the function

Answer (score 0):

.NET has the [`System.ArraySegment<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) structure which addresses this exact use-case.

But I’ve never actually seen this structure used in code, with good reasons: *it doesn’t work*. Notably, it doesn’t implement any interfaces such as `IEnumerable<T>`. The Linq solution (= using `Skip`) is consequently the best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most simple way to do this is:

```
public void MyFunction(ref int[] data,int index)
    {
        data[index]=10;
    }
```

And call it by this way:

```
int[] array= { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Myfunction(ref array,2);
foreach(int num in array)
    Console.WriteLine(num);
```

This will print 1,2,10,4,5

Answer (score -2):

```
public void MyFunc(ref int[] arr)
{
    // Do something
}

int[] myArray = .... ;
MyFunc(ref myArray);
```

See here for more information on [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)!

Comment: He wants to pass part of an array, no the whole thing. That's completely different.