# C# Passing array with specific array index

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, .net, ienumerable

I want to pass an array to a function with specific index in C#, like we do in C++, something like below:

```
void foo(int* B) {
// do something;
}

int main() {
int A[10];
foo(A + 3);
}
```

In this case suppose `A` starts with base address `1000`, then B would be `1000+(sizeof(int)*3)`. The answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788536/pass-array-to-function-from-specific-index-in-c-sharp-net) uses `Skip()` function call but in this case `B` should be of type `IEnumerable<int>` and on calling `Skip()` with `ToArray()` it creates a copy with different base address, but I want to pass this same array to function foo. How can we do that in C#?

Comment: Why not simply pass the array and the offset?  Yes, that is one extra parameter, but is that such a big deal?  Why overcomplicate things?  Maybe even the C++ code would be better off doing things that way, to be honest.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's quite a big deal. That is the opposite of dependency injection. Now _every_ array argument is two. The C++ code would preferably be a `std::span`.

Comment: I think you may be looking for “span”. It passes part of an array, but doesn’t make a copy. You may have only 1 element in your span, but I think it gives you what you want.

Comment: ^^ [All About Span: Exploring a New .NET Mainstay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/january/csharp-all-about-span-exploring-a-new-net-mainstay) & [Span<T> struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Note that you can use pointers in c# if you allow unsafe code, but `span<T>` is probably a better option in the vast majority of cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered here:
[C# Array slice without copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323994/c-sharp-array-slice-without-copy)

You can use ArraySegment or Span to achieve this

```
public static void Main()
{
    int[] arr1 = new int[] {2, 5, 8, 10, 12};
    int[] arr2 = new int[] {10, 20, 30, 40};

    DoSomethingWithSegmentReference(new ArraySegment<int>(arr1, 2, arr1.Length - 2));
    
    DoSomethingWithSpanReference(arr2.AsSpan().Slice(1, arr2.Length - 1));
}

private static void DoSomethingWithSegmentReference(ArraySegment<int> slice){
    for(int i = 0; i < slice.Count; i++)
        slice[i] = slice[i] * 2;
}

private static void DoSomethingWithSpanReference(Span<int> slice){
    for(int i = 0; i < slice.Length; i++)
        slice[i] = slice[i] * 2;
}
```

Comment: If you think this has been answered already, please mark it as duplicate instead.

Comment: I think he asked the same thing in a totally different way to think. I think his question is biased to a lower level lang like C and C++, thinking in passing pointers, memory address offsets and stuff. But in higher level langs such as C#, Golang, Python, JS, is quite common have classes or methods for array slicing he just didn't know that

Comment: Thanks Douglas, I think among ArraySegment and Span, the Span more fits in my requirements...